# Android overlapping card views animation

Tags: android, animation, swipe

I'm trying to do stack of cards overlapped that when the fist card is swiped out the next card from stack move ahead. I've searched for hours and I couldn't find any idea how to start doing this.

Do you guys have any idea how could I start this task?

Example of animation:
https://m2.behance.net/rendition/pm/18748605/disp/603b50f460bcf69b751bc8d2c1d39dbc.gif

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a few libraries for what you want. You could use them as a base to develop your own library.

https://github.com/kikoso/Swipeable-Cards

https://github.com/Diolor/Swipecards

https://github.com/ecstasy2/tinder-card-stack

Comment: Thanks Chilly Chan. =)